# Django queryset verify if fields exists

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to implement a custom ordering backend (using rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter) and I basically want to check if the field exists for my queryset first before filtering it without **evaluating the queryset**.

something like

```py
if queryset.is_available_field(my_field):
  queryset = queryset.order_by(my_field)
```

I cannot try / except because I don't know exactly when my queryset will be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution that works for my case but might not cover some edge cases. Also it is not very elegant.

```py
def has_field(queryset, field):
    model_fields = [f.name for f in queryset.model._meta.fields]
    annotations = list(queryset.query.annotations.keys())
    return field in model_fields + annotations
```

Comment: Although this doesn't work when ordering by related field